# Converting an array of single object arrays, to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have an array of arrays that looks like the following:

```js
const writeable = [
  [{id: 1, name: "item1", write: true}],
  [{id: 3, name: "item3", write: true}]
]
```

I would like to convert the array of arrays (all of which contain a single object) to an array of objects.

I have tried mapping through the `writeable` array and pushing each item into a new array, but because `.map` returns a new array, I'm left with the same result.  Is there a way to do this, or is this not possible?

The expected output:

```js
const newArray = [
  {id: 1, name: "item1", write: true},
  {id: 3, name: "item3", write: true}
]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: You'd need to use `.flatMap`  instead of `.map`. Or just `writeable.flat()` :-)

Comment: [].concat.apply([], writeable)

Comment: Or even `[].concat(...writeable)`

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: @NinaScholz I have added the desired result

Comment: it s a no brainer use what @Bergi suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat).

```js
const writeable = [
  [{id: 1, name: "item1", write: true}],
  [{id: 3, name: "item3", write: true}]
]
const res = writeable.flat();//default depth is 1
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the object inside the element you are iterating

```
writeable.map(function (item) {
  return item[0];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const writeable =[
[{id: 1, name: "item1", write: true}],
[{id: 3, name: "item3", write: true}]
];

let result = writeable.flat();

console.log(result);
```

Comment: overkill, just use .flat()

Comment: yes you are right. I thought too complicated. Editted it.